# Python Requests TLS session tickets are not supported (403 response)

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, openssl, urllib

I am trying to make a request to a server using Python Requests and it returns a 403. The page works fine using my browser and using `urllib`.

The **headers are identical**. I even tried using an ordered dict to make sure the header ordering is identical, but it still won't work.

Then I tried to see the SSL differences, and found that the main difference between the 3 (my browser, `requests`, and `urllib`) is that `requests` doesn't support TLS session tickets.

```
url="https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check"

import requests
req = requests.get(url=url)
print(req.text)

import urllib
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
print(response.read())
```

The Cipher Suite is almost identical across the 3. The TLS version is 1.3 across all. But the `session_ticket_supported` is **true** only for the browser and `urllib` (both of which work) and is **false** for `requests` (which returns 403).

So I assumed that the problem is there.

I dug deeper and learned that `requests` is actually using `urllib3`, but I got stuck at confirming which SSL adapter they use and how to configure it.

Any ideas on how to enable TLS session tickets for requests? Or maybe I am looking in the wrong place here?

PS. I am using Python 3.9.13 and the latest versions for all packages

PSS. `curl` also supports session tickets on my system and can access the server fine

Comment: *" I am looking in the wrong place here?"* - impossible to tell since there is nothing here for us to reproduce your problem. All what we have is your interpretation of your findings, but not the actual tests you've run, not the raw results you got and not the URL you are actually having problems with so we could try ourselves.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the url i am trying to open is https www investing dot com. The results I got from the SSL test were explained above: all identical except for the "session tickets supported" parameter. I am wondering why urllib and the browser gives "true" while requests gives "false".

Comment: I doubt that this has anything to do with session tickets. And I get different results. Depending on the Python and openssl version in use I get either 403 for both requests and urllib (openssl3, Python 3.10) or 200 for requests but 403 for urllib (Python 3.8, openssl 1.1.1). Culprit seems to be here the Cloudflare anti-bot detection.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that is very strange but similar to me. Yes I think it is Cloudflare's detection. But I was wondering what is different from my end when sending the requests? Headers are identical. What else could be different aside from the SSL? (I am talking about browser vs urllib vs requests).

Comment: *"The headers are identical"* - how do you know?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I checked here: https://httpbin.org/get unless there are other hidden headers that are not shown on that page?

Comment: The headers shown there are not in the order sent by the client but are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich so you say the issue is with the header orderings? I already tried using an ordered dict and it didn't make a difference for me.

Comment: I only say that you if you make assumptions about the order of the headers based on httpbin.org/get, then these assumptions will be wrong. And using an ordered dict does not change that you are basing your code on wrong assumption. There are a variety of questions on this site which deal with bypassing bot protection by Cloudflare and Akamai. Sometimes a different header order or some additional header does the job. Note that these CDN continuously improve their bot detection so any previous answers might be outdated.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I see, thanks for the tips. Any idea how else Python requests can be fingerprinted comparing to browser requests? JS functionality, header orders, SSL, thats it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249205/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-john-mc).